# How to detect a user's choice in C

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

Please help! I'm taking a class for C coding, and the professor wants us to make a program that:

1. Has a user choose circle, triangle, or rectangle.
2. Then based on their answer, wants us to find the circumference/area (circle) area/perimeter (rectangle) and area (triangle) based on which one was chosen.

I'm struggling so hard with the scanf() function right now. Below is what I have so far qwq. I have very little experience with javascript from a few years ago but I am so stuck right now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void){
    //declare variable
    int circle=1;
    int triangle=2;
    int rectangle=3;
    int testChoice;
    //prompt for choice
    printf("Select 1 for circle. Select 2 for triangle. Select 3 for rectangle.");
    scanf("%d", &testChoice);
    
    //circle
    if(&testChoice=="1")
        printf("Circle");
    //triangle
    if(&testChoice=="2")
        printf("Triangle");
    //rectangle
    if(&testChoice=="3")
        printf("Rectangle");
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what you think `&testChoice=="1"` is doing? What are the types on the left-hand and right-hand sides of `==`, and what do you think comparing those types with `==` will do?

Comment: And what are you doing with these variables: `int circle=1;
    int triangle=2;
    int rectangle=3;`?

Comment: Basically you cannot program by trial & error. The code posted here is just a bunch of wild guessing, that's not how programming works. You actually have to know what everything you write does and the only way to learn that is to study.

Comment: so the gag is that i dont know how to code and this was a program i was expected to finish in a day when the most my professor has done is demonstrate how the printf function works. unfortunately for me it is guesswork!

Answer (score 0):

Remove both the extra `&` and `" "` in your if-statements.

Why did you put them there in the first place???

```
    //circle
    if( testChoice == 1)
        printf("Circle");
    //triangle
    if( testChoice == 2 )
        printf("Triangle");
    //rectangle
    if( testChoice == 3 )
        printf("Rectangle");
    }
```

Comment: Also, check the return value of `scanf`. If it fails to read a value, `testChoice` is uninitialized and this leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! My professor kept using the "&" symbol in the example code he posted, so I was copying him qwq

Answer (score 0):

Update... I did it! It's messy and gross but it is done.
I know this has no need to be as lengthy as it is, however, it functions. I've only ever used block coding and a little bit of javascript, so I'm proud.
If anyone has any tips to make this code not as ugly I would appreciate that :p

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{

//declare variables

  int testChoice;
  int choice2;
  float radius, circleArea, circumfrence, length, width,
    rectangleArea, rectanglePerimeter, height, lengthOfBase, triangleArea;

//prompt for choice

  printf
    ("Select 1 for circle. Select 2 for rectangle. Select 3 for triangle.\n");
  scanf ("%d", &testChoice);

//circle

  if (testChoice == 1)
    {

//select area or circumfrence for circle.

      printf
    ("Select 1 for area of the circle. Select 2 for circumfrence.\n");
      scanf ("%d", &choice2);

//circle area

      if (choice2 == 1)
    {
      printf ("Please provide the radius of the circle.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &radius);
      circleArea = 3.14159 * radius * radius;
      printf ("The area of the circle = %.2f\n", circleArea);
    }

//circle circumfrence

      if (choice2 == 2)
    {
      printf ("Please provide the radius of the circle.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &radius);
      circumfrence = 2 * 3.14159 * radius;
      printf ("The circumfrence of the circle = %.2f\n", circumfrence);
    }
      else
    (printf ("Invalid selection. Terminating program."));
    }


  //rectangle

  if (testChoice == 2)
    {
        
//select area or perimeter for the rectangle. 
        
      printf
    ("Select 1 for area of the Rectangle. Select 2 for perimeter.\n");
      scanf ("%d", &choice2);

//rectangle area

      if (choice2 == 1)
    {
      printf ("Please input the length.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &length);
      printf ("Please input the width.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &width);
      rectangleArea = length * width;
      printf ("The area of the rectangle = %f\n", rectangleArea);
    }

//rectangle perimeter

      if (choice2 == 2)
    {
      printf ("Please input the length.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &length);
      printf ("Please input the width.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &width);
      rectanglePerimeter = 2 * (length + width);
      printf ("The perimeter of the rectangle = %f\n",
          rectanglePerimeter);
    }
      else
    (printf ("Invalid selection. Terminating program."));
    }

  //triangle input

  if (testChoice == 3)
    {
      printf ("Please input the height.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &height);
      printf ("Please input the length of the base.\n");
      scanf ("%f", &lengthOfBase);
      triangleArea = (height * lengthOfBase) / 2;
      printf ("The area of the triangle = %f\n", triangleArea);
    }
    
//if/else statement for out of bounds inputs. 
    
  else
    (printf ("Invalid selection. Terminating program."));
}
```